# Cardinality of a line segment

Tags: proof-verification, cardinals

If ${(a,b)}$ and ${(c,d)}$ are points in $ℝ^2$ then let $S$ be the set of point on the line segment that joins ${(a,b)}$ and ${(c,d)}$. Show $|S|= |ℝ|$

I can see this is similar to how the tangent function maps from the inverval ${(-\frac{\pi}2},\frac{\pi}2)$ to the set of real numbers but i'm not sure how to show that this is general for any line segment?

**Added:**

Could we write this line segment as an interval: $[(a,b),(c,d)]=(a+t(c-a),b+t(d-b)$ where $t \in [0,1]$ and then use the theorem that says $|[e,f]| = |[0,1]|$ where we let $e=a+t(c-a)$ and $f=b+t(d-b)$ and then from this use the theorem that states the cardinality of the set of all real numbers is the same as the cardinality of $[0,1]$? This almost seems too simple because I just strung together some theorems?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write down a precise parametrization (bijection) of your segment by an interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with a line segment in $ℝ^2$ instead of with just an interval in $ℝ$

Comment: How is that segment expressed ?

Comment: would my interval be ${((a,b),(c,d))}$?

Comment: no, $[(a,b),(c,d)]=\{ (a+t(c-a),b+t(d-b)):t \in [0,1]\}$

Comment: Are you saying that $[(a,b),(c,d)]={(a+t(c−a),b+t(d−b)):t∈[0,1]}$ is the interval?

Comment: Ok, so then i see that when t=0 we have the point (a,b) and when t=1 we have the point (c,d) that makes sense. So now to show a bijection I have to show that there is a function that is one to one and onto that maps this interval to the set of real numbers?

Comment: Alternatively, if the segment is vertical, then projection onto the $y$-axis gives a bijection onto an interval on the $y$-axis, and if the segment is not vertical, then projection onto the $x$-axis gives a bijection onto an interval on the $x$-axis.